# Kernel size can't be greater than actual input size

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have a data with depth = 3 and I want to pass it through 3 convolution layers with 3x3x3 kernels each.
My current code is below. The first input is 
[batch_size=10, in_channels=1, depth=3, height=128, width=256] 
and I notice after the first conv3d layer the output is [10,8,1,126,254]. Obviously it has now depth 1 and doesn't accept it for another 3x3x3 layer. How can I achieve this?

```
class CNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv3d(1, 8, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=0)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv3d(8, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=0)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv3d(16, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=0)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(value, 2)

    def forward(self, X):
        X = F.relu(self.conv1(X))
        X = F.relu(self.conv2(X))
        X = F.max_pool2d(X,2)
        X = self.conv3(X)
        X = F.max_pool2d(X,2)
        X = self.fc1(X)
        return F.softmax(X,dim =1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use padding. If you only want to pad the input for the convolutions after the first one and only in the depth dimensions to get the minimum dimension of 3, you would use `padding=(1, 0, 0)` (it's 1 because the same padding is applied to both sides, i.e. *(padding, input, padding)* along that dimension).

```py
self.conv2 = nn.Conv3d(8, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=(1, 0, 0))
self.conv3 = nn.Conv3d(16, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=(1, 0, 0))
```

However, it is common to use `padding=1` for all dimensions when using `kernel_size=3`, because that keeps the dimensions unchanged, which makes it much easier to build deeper network, as you don't need to worry about the sizes suddenly getting too small, as it happened already for your depth dimension. Also when no padding is used, the corners are only included in a single calculation, whereas all other elements contribute to multiple calculations. It is recommended to use `kernel_size=3` and `padding=1` for all your convolutions.

```py
self.conv1 = nn.Conv3d(1, 8, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
self.conv2 = nn.Conv3d(8, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
self.conv3 = nn.Conv3d(16, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
```

Comment: thank you for this very clear and thorough explanation. the task i have specifies that I use no padding. im assuming this is impossible?

Comment: You're right, that is impossible, unless you can make the depth dimension bigger to begin with, that would be most likely padding anyway, so you might as well let the convolution handle the padding. Another approach would be to duplicate the input, i.e. you just repeat it multiple times across the depth dimensions, but frankly that sounds very questionable.

Comment: Now that I think about it, are you sure you want to use 3D convolutions? Later you are using 2D max pooling. And your input looks suspiciously like an RGB image `[3, 128, 256] = [channels (RGB), height, width]`, if it is supposed to be an image, you should use `Conv2d`.